# Table-like layout with arbitrary column widths, without exceeding parent bounds

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a table-like layout with two columns of arbitrary (non-knowable) data. The second column has the potential to contain very long strings, particularly URLs. I would like to set up the table in such a way that the width of the first column corresponds to its widest cell, and the width of the second column fills the remaining space, up to the bounds of its parent.

Unfortunately, i can't seem to achieve both of these requirements in all browsers — only one or the other.

My original thought was this:

```
<div>
    <dl style="display: table-row;">
        <dt style="display: table-cell; white-space: nowrap;">abc</dt>
        <dd style="display: table-cell; word-wrap: break-word;">asdfasdfadfadsfadfadf</dt>
    </dl>

    ...
</div>
```

And in Firefox, this works perfectly. Each `<dl>` acts as a `<tr>`, and the first column is exactly as wide as the widest `<dt>`.

However, in WebKit and Opera (why not), this leads to the second column (the `<dd>`s) over-flowing the bounds of the `<div>`.

I was able to correct that problem by changing the parent `<div>` like so:

```
<div style="display: table; table-layout: fixed;">
```

But when i do this, it forces all browsers (including Firefox) to make each column exactly 50% the width of the parent, which is not ideal because the first column will usually be narrower than the second (leading to wasted space).

Here are some diagrams, if it's not clear what i'm talking about: http://pastie.org/pastes/8040093/text?key=orwbkirzd4vdt611mmwaxw

Is there a way to do this without explicitly defining the width of the first column? Legacy browsers are not a concern, so if it's CSS3 that's fine.

Comment: What you would like is for the table width algorithm to do the following: shrink-to-fit the content of the first column cells and fill the remaining width with the second column.  There is no way of explicitly triggering that.  Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to set the width of dt.  CSS by itself won't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me in firefox and chrome:

```
<div style="display:table; table-layout:auto; width: 100%;">
    <dl style="display: table-row;">
        <dt style="display: table-cell; white-space: nowrap;">abc</dt>
        <dd style="display: table-cell; word-wrap: break-word;
            word-break:break-all;">
            asdfasdfadfadsfadfadf asdfasdfadfadsfadfadf
            asdfasdfadfadsfadfadf asdfasdfadfadsfadfadf</dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kingmotley/AFHnE/6/

Comment: Yeah, I noticed as soon as you apply a width it breaks.

Comment: Updated answer to handle tables with a fixed width, and a second column that may have text that is too long to fit on a single line.  Tested in firefox, chrome, and IE 10.

Comment: The addition of `word-break: break-all` was the key addition here. It's not ideal, but it sounds like the best i can get for now. Thanks!